# Range Error when using application.worksheetfunction.Vlookup in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, range, vlookup, worksheet-function

i have the following piece of code:

```
Function MyLookup(var1 As Variant, range1 As Range, var2 As Integer) As Double
MyLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(var1, range1, var2, False)
End Function
```

I use this function to calculate some of the parameters in the following function

```
Function Test(IntMethod As String, CFDate As Date, ValDate As Date, _
              CF As Double, RepFreq As Integer, DiscToDate As String, _
              DiscType As String) As Double
Dim InterpPeriod As Double, PrevDateRate As Double, _
    CurrDateRate As Double, PrevCurvMat As Integer, _
    CurrCurvMat As Integer, rate As Double
Dim Yield_Curves As Range, PrevValDate As Date

Set Yield_Curves = DISC_CFS.Range("Yield_Curves")
PrevValDate = Last_Period(ValDate, CFDate, RepFreq)
'-----------------------------------------------------
InterpPeriod = Application.WorksheetFunction.YearFrac(CFDate, ValDate, 1)
PrevCurvMat = YearsDiff(ValDate, CFDate)
CurrCurvMat = YearsDiff(ValDate, CFDate) + 1
PrevDateRate = MyLookup(PrevValDate, Yield_Curves, 2)
CurrDateRate = MyLookup(ValDate, Yield_Curves, 2)
```

when i get to MyLookup function, the range is not recognised and it exits  the function.
Any hints?

thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?  FYI when using `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` if there's no match you will get a run-time error which will halt your code if you have no error handling.  It's better to use `Application.VLookup` which if there's no match will return an error value you can test using `IsError()` (and change the return value of your function to Variant, not Double)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. i have an "add watch" window for the defined range. when it reaches the vlookup function and it runs it the Value column in the window becomes "out of context" from which i understand that it does not pick up the range. after this line, it exits the code and i get a VALUE in my respective cell

Comment: @TimWilliams  i have tried your suggestion and i end up with Error 2042 which indicates that it does not find a match, which is strange as the defined range is correct (5 column, multiple rows range and i want column 2 for the date that is already calculated). could this be a formatting issue? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to resolve the issue. The error was in one of my lookup variables, which was a date. The date should be converted to long type.

the correct code is the following:

```
Function MyLookup(var1 As Variant, range1 As Range, var2 As Integer) As Double
MyLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(var1, range1, var2, False)
End Function
```

And for the main code:

```
Function Test(IntMethod As String, CFDate As Date, ValDate As Date, _
              CF As Double, RepFreq As Integer, DiscToDate As String, _
              DiscType As String) As Double
Dim InterpPeriod As Double, PrevDateRate As Double, _
    CurrDateRate As Double, PrevCurvMat As Integer, _
    CurrCurvMat As Integer, rate As Double
Dim Yield_Curves As Range, PrevValDate As Date

Set Yield_Curves = DISC_CFS.Range("Yield_Curves")
PrevValDate = Last_Period(ValDate, CFDate, RepFreq)
'-----------------------------------------------------
InterpPeriod = Application.WorksheetFunction.YearFrac(CFDate, ValDate, 1)
PrevCurvMat = YearsDiff(ValDate, CFDate)
CurrCurvMat = YearsDiff(ValDate, CFDate) + 1
PrevDateRate = MyLookup(CLng(PrevValDate), Yield_Curves, 2)
CurrDateRate = MyLookup(CLng(ValDate), Yield_Curves, 2)
```

thank you for the provided answers and assistance